# ASP.NET Domain Controls

Tags: asp.net, windows

a client asked me today about having users be able to have their own domains within the web application.

example would be:

> http://example.com/User/View.aspx?=60
>   would change into http://userpage.com/

I am not sure how to approach this, can anyone provide me few pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is complete documentation from Microsoft on how to use **multiple host headers**.  Essentially, you configure the web server (IIS) with multiple web sites, then within each website you configure the list of host headers that the site should respond to.  This allows you to host multiple sites on the same server:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190008  (or similar articles for other versions, such as http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28WS.10%29.aspx  or  http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e7a21b1f-ab13-47f2-8c61-b09cf14a7cb3.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: It is IIS that receives the request and then chooses to route it to the ASP.Net engine to process the request.  But all the domain mapping of URL to specific website is done in IIS before it ever hands the request off to ASP.Net to process.  So you can't really do this within ASP.Net.  However, you may be able to use alternate approaches--such as using a single domain, but then creating separate .Net applications for separate folders within that domain.  Then you can treat each folder/virtual as a separate application if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Provided they have the domain and it is on a client's server, you can forward based on the id presented (60).

If http://userpage.webapp.com, you can use routing rules in ASP.NET 4.0 to handle this (some functionality in 3.5, I think, but 4.0 is better).

Comment: Client's web application is built on 2.0 framework... Upgrading will be a disaster. Is there a routing method in 2.0 framework that I could use?